# Adding a base URL to an app using Redux-Router + React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm using [React-Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) 1.0.0-rc3 together with [Redux-Router](https://github.com/rackt/redux-router) 1.0.0-beta3.

When using React-Router, you can use `useBasename` with `createHistory` to set the base URL for an app, so that you can easily write an app that runs inside a subdirectory. [Example](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/353#issuecomment-148385993):

Instead of this:

```
import { createHistory } from 'history';

let base = "/app_name/"

<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path={base} component={App}></Route>
</Router>

<Link path={base + "some_path"}>some_path</Link>
```

You can write in this way using `useBasename`:

```
import { createHistory, useBasename } from 'history';

const browserHistory = useBasename(createHistory)({
  basename: "/app_name"
});

<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}></Route>
</Router>

<Link path="/some_path">some_path</Link>
```

However, in Redux-Router, you need to pass `createHistory` instead of `history` to a reducer:

```
const store = compose(
  applyMiddleware(m1, m2, m3),
  reduxReactRouter({
    routes,
    createHistory
  }),
  devTools()
)(createStore)(reducer);
```

How can we use `useBasename` in this case?

Comment: I am not sure what the second example ( "You can write in this way using useBasename") means.  It seems to be using the "history" module (not part of React).  Also, if you are already using an imported "browserHistory" object from react-router, you cannot overwrite it with a "const browserHistory" definition.  And if I replace that with "newBrowserHistory" instead, I get the error "TypeError: _history.useBasename is not a function".  So I honestly cannot make heads or tails of the example.

Answer (score 13):

For react-router v2 or v3 and using [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) v4 instead of redux-router, the setup of the history object will look like this:

```
import { createHistory } from 'history'
import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'

const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
  basename: '<yourBaseUrl>'
})
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)
```

The rest of the setup is as usual when there is no extra base URL.

Comment: Works perfectly, recommended if you're using the latest `react-router` and `react-router-redux`

Comment: I'm not using react-router-redux (just regular react-router) but the above code worked for me with the omission of the last line.

Comment: I can't get this to work with the latest version of history: `createHistory is not a function`. If I `const createHistory = require('history').createBrowserHistory;` then my route does not seem to get matched with a `basename: '/'`. Any idea?

Comment: I just got it to work using the same (old) version of `history` as `react-router@2.8.1` does: `history@2.1.2`. If anyone gets this to work with one of the latest versions, (e.g. `history@4.3.0`) please let me know.

Comment: @DamianoBarbati You can't downvote this answer just because it does not work for you _now_. It is a properly written answer to the original question. Please use your [vote down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) privilege maturely.

Comment: A variant of this that worked for me (without knowing what I was doing):
import { createHistory } from 'history'
import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
const _browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
  basename: '/academy'
})

const store = createStore(_browserHistory, api, window.__data)
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(_browserHistory, store)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function that wraps `useBasename`:

```
const createHistoryWithBasename = (historyOptions) => {
  return useBasename(createHistory)({
    basename: '/app_name',
    ...historyOptions
  })
}
```

And pass it to `compose`:

```
const store = compose(
  applyMiddleware(m1, m2, m3),
  reduxReactRouter({
    routes,
    createHistory: createHistoryWithBaseName
  }),
  devTools()
)(createStore)(reducer);
```

Answer (score 1):

The API changes very often so this is what worked for me (I'm using the `2.0.3` version of `redux-simple-router`). I have defined the custom history in a separate file:

```js
import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import { createHistory, useBasename } from 'history'
import { baseUrl } from '../config'

const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(useBasename(createHistory))({
  basename: "/appgen"
});
```

Now I need to initialize the store:

```js
import { syncHistory, routeReducer } from 'redux-simple-router'
import browserHistory from '../misc/browserHistory'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // ...other reducers
  routing: routeReducer
});

const reduxRouterMiddleware = syncHistory(browserHistory);

const finalCreateStore = compose(
  // ...other middleware
  applyMiddleware(reduxRouterMiddleware),
)(createStore);


const store = finalCreateStore(rootReducer, initialState);
```

Eventually, you need to pass the `history` to the `Router`.

```js
import browserHistory from './misc/browserHistory'
import routes from '../routes'

export default class Root extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        {routes}
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

---

Before I came up with this, I was using a *manual* solution. I defined my own `Link` component and my own redux action that were responsible for prepending the base URL. It might be useful for someone.

Updated `Link` component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router'
import { baseUrl } from '../config'

export default class Link extends Component {
  render() {
    return <RouterLink {...this.props} to={baseUrl + '/' + this.props.to} />
  }
}
```

Custom action creator:

```js
import { routeActions } from 'redux-simple-router'
import { baseUrl } from '../config'

export function goTo(path) {
  return routeActions.push(baseUrl + '/' + path);
}
```

Updated root route:

```js
import { baseUrl } from './config'
export default (
  <Route component={App} path={baseUrl}>
    //...nested routes
  </Route>
);
```

Note that these custom tools only support pushing updated paths, not the *location descriptor object*.

Comment: Do you use "browserHistory.push('/otherPage')"? if so - did you setup something else to make it work? I loose the basename when i do...

Comment: Nope. It's been a while now but I would say that the right thing to do is to dispatch the `goTo` action rather than using the low-level API manually.

Answer (score -1):

A variant of Diego V's answer that worked for me (without knowing what I was doing):

```
import { createHistory } from 'history'
import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
...

const _browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
  basename: '/yourbase'
})

const store = createStore(_browserHistory, api, window.__data)
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(_browserHistory, store)
```

I was replacing:

```
//const _browserHistory = useScroll(() => browserHistory)()
```