# React Router base URL issue and link tag issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an existing application in ASP.NET Web Form hosted in IIS. Now I have created a new directory under the root named **mobile**. URL is like - http://domainname/mobile.

Application is written using React, Redux and React Router. Now to run the application I have made changes in the Routes.js as follows -

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route path='/mobile' component={App}>
        <Route path='/thankyou' component={ThankYou} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Main page is loaded correctly because root component has a path of '/mobile'. But when I try to access thankyou Component using the link tag with to pointing to thankyou. It did not work.

I have tried various changes - using basename or history or various suggested solutions provided on react-router github but these also not working. My libraries version in package.json

```
"react": "15.0.2",
"react-dom": "15.0.2",
"react-redux": "4.4.5",
"react-router": "2.4.0",
"react-router-redux": "4.0.4",
```

Anybody who can provide a working solution with baseURL set up as "/mobile"?

Possible Duplicate - [React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376414/adding-a-base-url-to-an-app-using-redux-router-react-router)

Answer (score 1):

Your root route should be `/` if the /mobile url is provided by the server and not the front end, as in:

```
<Route path="/" component={ App }>
    <Route path="thankyou" component={ ThankYou } />
</Route>
```

This makes `/mobile/#/thankyou` accessible.

Comment: I am not using hashhistory. This will not be directly accessible as there is no such page. I have tried rewriting the URL so that whenever /mobile is there, my page is return as output. After doing this rewriting change, I can access the page directly. But <Link to= "thankyou"> is still not working. It still points to domain/thankyou where it should point to domain/mobile/thankyou